# Splitting a string in Python 2.7

Tags: python, facebook, python-2.7, replace, skype4py

I want to know how to allow multiple inputs in Python. 
Ex: If a message is "!comment postid customcomment" 
I want to be able to take that post ID, put that somewhere, and then the customcomment, and put that somewhere else. 
Here's my code:

```
import fb
token="access_token_here"
facebook=fb.graph.api(token)

#__________ Later on in the code: __________

                elif msg.startswith('!comment '):
                    postid = msg.replace('!comment ','',1)
                    send('Commenting...')
                    facebook.publish(cat="comments", id=postid, message="customcomment")
                    send('Commented!')
```

I can't seem to figure it out. 
Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't quite tell what you are asking but it seems that this will do what you want.
Assuming that 
`msg = "!comment postid customcomment"`
you can use the built-in string method [`split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to turn the string into a list of strings, using `" "` as a separator and a maximum number of splits of 2:

`msg_list=msg.split(" ",2)`

the zeroth index will contain "!comment" so you can ignore it

`postid=msg_list[1]` or `postid=int(msg_list[1])` if you need a numerical input

`message = msg_list[2]`

If you don't limit split and just use the default behavior (ie `msg_list=msg.split()`), you would have to rejoin the rest of the strings separated by spaces.  To do so you can use the built-in string method [`join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) which does just that:

`message=" ".join(msg_list[2:])`

and finally

`facebook.publish(cat="comments", id=postid, message=message)`

Comment: Well, i'd need it to remove "!comment " and then put the post ID in the id section, and then the message in the message section. 

Meaning: !comment 987654321 Hello

It'd comment on the post number 987654321 saying "Hello". 

That's why I use ` postid = msg.replace('!comment ','',1) `

I had it to where it posted a generic comment, if the user put in the post ID. What came after "!comment " was the post ID. It replaced the "!comment " with nothing, thus only leaving the postID, thus the reason why I did "id=postid"

Sorry if this sounds confusing. I haven't slept from trying to figure this out

Comment: But what does the full `msg` string look like?

Comment: `msg = self.Message.Body` -- 
Basically, if message is received. This is a Skype bot I'm working on. 

So, if I get a message from someone saying "!comment 234567 This is a comment" I want it to be able to recognize which is the post ID and which is the custom comment.

Comment: ok, i'll rephrase it.  what does `print msg` or in py3k `print(msg)` look like?

Comment: Yeah, I fixed my comment. Sorry. 
Basically, to make this an easier question.

Let's say I had a string that was 
"Cats like yarn"
How would I be able to break down the string into 3? Meaning one being "cats" one being "like" and one being "Yarn" so I can later do something like ` print word1, word3 `

Comment: Of course the string wouldn't be fixed. It'd be custom. Ex: I can type a string and it'll break it down for me. So it won't necessarily be "cats like yarn"

Comment: split and join should do everything you need, I edited my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: ``split`` takes a couple of optional arguments: (1) the character(s) on which to split the string, and (2) the maximum number of splits.  So if you say ``msg.split(' ', 2)`` -- you get three strings back.  You don't have to join all the remaining strings back together again.